# How to write a %macro creating SAS data sets from csv files, using a prespecified variable formats?

Tags: sas

How to import a csv in SAS with the formats of an existing SAS dataset and how to create a macro from this process?

Suppose I managed to load the data from 5 csv files in datasets having convenient formats. Now I am regularly delivered new versions (v2, v3, ...) of these files and I want to load the data in new datasets, having the same format as the old ones.

How do I write a macro for that?

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Suppose there are 5 SAS old data sets with version v2 in a library and there are 5 new csv's with version v3 and the task is to import new csv's into SAS with the older formats(from v2). And this process should be automated in such a manner that it looks for the csv name and version, takes out it's headers first and then uses the formats of old sas data sets(v2) and creates new sas data set v3. Thanks!

Comment: I hope I interpreted this correctly.

Comment: @tarun add you edit to your question please. I'm assuming you already have working proc import code? If so, please post a sample otherwise we'll assume it <working proc import>.

Comment: Please add more information, so we understand why (you think) you need a macro.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to

1. inspect the structure of you existing dataset with a `proc contents`
2. read the data from the newly arrived file with `proc import`
3. copy the data step generated by `proc import` from the log file
4. modify it to comply with the desired structure (formats)
5. parametrise it with some macro variables
6. make these macro variables parameters of your macro.

Alternatively add some prompts to the program in Enterprise Guide

For instance suppose `proc contents data=mydata; run;` gives you among other information this

```
Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes         
#   Variable    Type    Len
3   long        Char    50
1   num         Num     8
2   short       Char    8
```

Importing this

```
num,kort,lang
4,alfa,A short sentence
5,beta,And another one
```

with this

```
proc import replace
    datafile='c:\TEMP\csv_v3.csv' 
    out=myData;
    format num 8. kort $8. lang $33.;
run;
```

reads as this in the log

```
29          /**********************************************************************
30          *   PRODUCT:   SAS
31          *   VERSION:   9.4
32          *   CREATOR:   External File Interface
33          *   DATE:      15MAY16
34          *   DESC:      Generated SAS Datastep Code
35          *   TEMPLATE SOURCE:  (None Specified.)
36          ***********************************************************************/
37             data WORK.MYDATA    ;
38             %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
39             infile 'c:\TEMP\csv_v3.csv' delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
40                informat num best32. ;
41                informat kort $4. ;
42                informat lang $16. ;
43                format num best12. ;
44                format kort $4. ;
45                format lang $16. ;
46             input
47                         num
48                         kort $
49                         lang $
50             ;
51             if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
52             run;
```

which you can customise as

```
%macro importMyData(csvName);
data WORK.MYDATA;
/*  The first dot in &csvName..csv below closes the macro variable name, 
    so you need the second too */
    infile "c:\TEMP\&csvName..csv" 
        delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
/*  Note the firstobs option, which skips the headers! */

/*  Set the formats accordign to the output of proc contents */
    format num 8. ;
    format kort $8. ;
    format lang $50. ;

/*  Potentially you need to set a few informats too 
    I left one as an example */
    informat num best32. ;

    input
            num
            kort $
            lang $
    ;
run;
%mend;
%importMyData(csv_v3.csv);
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk for giving me a solution.
I need a macro because there can be n number of csv's, so one would not want to go and edit the code for each and every csv. The code in itself should take care of formats to be taken from the prev version of sas data set and to be used in proc import or infile statement to get a new sas data set.

Comment: With `proc contents noprint date=myData out=myStructure;` you get the same information in a dataset. From this, you can automatically build a data step to read in a csv with appropriate input, except that you might need to tune it to the formats used in your csv. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

So if the structure of the new CSV files matches the structure of the existing datasets then you should be able to have a program as simple as this:

```
data new ;
  if 0 then set old ;
  infile "new.csv" dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
  input (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

You could convert that to a macro by first replacing the input dataset, model dataset and output dataset with macro variables.

```
%macro readcsv(infile,out,model);
data &out;
  if 0 then set &model;
  infile "&infile" dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
  input (_all_) (+0);
run;
%mend readcsv;
```

So a call to the macro might look like:

```
%readcsv(infile=file1_v2.csv,out=mylib.file1_v2,model=mylib.file1)
```

The trouble will come if the input CSV file does not follow the model. So if the columns are in the wrong order then the data will be read into the wrong fields.  Also you will need to make sure you have associated INFORMATs with the variables, like date and time values, that will need them in the model datasets.

You could fix the column order issue by replacing the `_all_` in the input statement with the list of names in the CSV file.  But this would require that the names match the model variable names. The previous version just requires that the order of the columns match the model.

```
%macro readcsv2(infile,out,model);
%local names ;
data _null_;
  infile "&infile" obs=1;
  input;
  call symputx('names',translate(_infile_,' ',','));
run;
data &out;
  if 0 then set &model;
  infile "&infile" dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
  input (&names) (+0);
run;
%mend readcsv2;
```

Comment: This is an intriguing solution. Would you care to elaborate as to how this would work?

Comment: I expanded the answer.